# How to make a Card in Jetpack compose appear selected when a DropDownMenu within it is expanded

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Hello Jetpack compose experts, please how can I make a Card in Jetpack compose to appear selected when a DropDownMenu within it is expanded. I tried the following but it didn't work. Thanks.

```
var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

Card(Modifier
            .selectable(
                selected = expanded,
                onClick = {}
            )) {
   Box{
       IconButton(
            onClick = {
                expanded = true
            }) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.MoreVert,
                contentDescription = ""
            )
        }
       DropDownMenu(expanded = expanded, onDismissRequest = {
            expanded = false
        }){
             DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("Edit") }, onClick = onEditClicked, leadingIcon = {
                Icon(
                    Icons.Default.Edit,
                    contentDescription = ""
                )
            })

        } 
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: For dropdowns you need a text field with modifier `menuAnchor`
Can see here. [example](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/make-it-so-android/blob/main/final/app/src/main/java/com/example/makeitso/common/composable/DropdownComposable.kt)

Answer (score 0):

You can play with Modifier.background() and supply the highlighted color as background to the card when expanded and transparent color while not expanded.

`Card(Modifier.background( if(expanded) Color.LightGray else Color.Transparent)) { }`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but its not exactly what am looking for. I don't want to provide a custom background color but rather use the inbuilt color the Card has when it is selected. If I knew exactly what this color was I would use your approach. I am using a MaterialTheme